# How do I add a sliding knockback force when shooting?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I call my Shoot() function I would like my character to be pushed back as if on ice. I have managed to use AddForce to push the character back but it happens instantly. I want the knock-back to gradually push the character back.

```
public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour{


public Rigidbody characterKnockback;
public Transform firePoint;
public GameObject bulletPrefab;
public float bulletForce = 20f;

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        Shoot();
        characterKnockback.AddForce(Vector3.back * 25f * bulletForce);
    }
}

void Shoot()
{
    GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
    Rigidbody rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rb.AddForce(firePoint.up * bulletForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
}}
```

Comment: Sounds like your friction is too high. Impulse is always instantaneous and the physics engine deals with it over time on its own. If you aren't getting floaty drift, then your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: What Draco18s said and are you sure the direction is correct? `Vector3.back` would be a global World-Space direction independently in which direction you shoot... You probably rather want something like `characterKnockBack.transform.forward * -25 * bulletForce` ...Also as said you have to calculate enough force depending on the mass and friction of the object..

Comment: For the bullet I would actually not use `AddForce` at all but rather directly set `rb.velocity = `

Comment: How would I set an rb.velocity fairly new at this? Maybe I'll attach a video of what's happening